# JSF Validation no wok in template

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

JSF validation are not working When i submit ,I under the myfaces(2.1.10) and mojarra(2.1.21) has tried, as same results.here is my code.Theoretically not execute onSubmit() and display error messages in m_name.But in fact is execute onSubmit() and not display error message.

template.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
    <title>Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
        <ui:insert name="body"></ui:insert>
</h:body>
</html>
```

template client file templatevalidation.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    template="/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="body">
        <h:form>
            <div>
                <h:inputText id="name" value="#{templateBean.name}">
                    <f:validateRequired />
                    <f:validateLength minimum="5" />
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message id="m_name" for="name" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <h:commandButton action="#{templateBean.onSubmit}" value="submit">
                    <f:ajax execute="name" render="m_name" />
                </h:commandButton>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

here is my bean TemplateBean.class

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TemplateBean implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9009393522101806766L;

    private String name;

    public void onSubmit(){
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Must use hibernate-validation

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `<h:message>` component after the AJAX call to show the error message using the `render` attribute in your `<f:ajax>` tag:

```
<h:message id="nameMsg" for="name" />

<h:commandButton action="#{templateBean.onSubmit}" value="submit">
    <f:ajax execute="name" render="nameMsg" />
</h:commandButton>
```